# Check that object is null in solidity mapping

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I have this solidity mapping

```
mapping (string => Ticket) public myMapping;
```

I want to check if `myMapping[key]` exists or not. How can I check?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The entire storage space is virtually initialized to 0 (there is no undefined). 
So you have to compare the value to the 0 value for your type. 
For example, mapping[key] == address(0x0) or mapping[key] = bytes4(0x0).

Answer (score 8):

There is no direct method to check whether the mapping has particular key. But you can check if mapping property has value or not. The following example considered that the `Ticket` is the struct with some property.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;

contract Test {

    struct Ticket {
       uint seatNumber;
    }

    mapping (string => Ticket) myMapping;

    function isExists(string memory key) public view returns (bool) {

        if(myMapping[key].seatNumber != 0){
            return true;
        } 
        return false;
    }

    function add(string memory key, uint seatNumber) public returns (bool){            
        myMapping[key].seatNumber = seatNumber;            
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract BookLibNew{

    address public owner;

    constructor() public{
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    modifier onlyOwner(){
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    struct bookDet{
        uint bookId;
        string bookTitle;
        string bookAuthor;
    }

    mapping (uint8 => bookDet) public bookLib;
    function addBookLib(uint8 _bookId, string memory _bookTitle, string memory _bookAuthor) 
    public onlyOwner {
        require(bookLib(_bookId) == false, "Error: Book already exists");
        bookLib[_bookId].bookTitle = _bookTitle;
        bookLib[_bookId].bookAuthor = _bookAuthor;
    }

    function readBookDetails(uint8 _bookId) public view returns(string memory, string memory){
        return(bookLib[_bookId].bookTitle, bookLib[_bookId].bookAuthor);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting type error in this is line of code "require(bookLib(_bookId) == false, "Error: Book already exists");" here i trying to check whether the book has already added or not. How can i check here?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).